# Is it good practice to use template classes to avoid creating a static library?

Tags: c++, templates, porting

I’m porting a lock-free container from C to C++. I’m now considering templating the class and using only one file so that the final user doesn’t have to go through the trouble of linking my lib. He would only have to include the template file.

I’m not sure if I’m doing the right thing though. Is this good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty common; Boost and many other C++ libraries are designed as header-only (though some parts of Boost need compilation). The same was true for the STL, which is now merged into the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Almost the entire C++ standard library is written like that, too, so you're in good hands.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the size of the code. The only issue to consider is the size you'll get from inlining. If you make sure the code in each template function is small then it should be alright. Just to motivate, all standard containers are header-only.

Comment: Well, templates must be defined in the header, which in turn allows the compiler to inline them. Of course, the compiler _should_ be smart enough to make an educated decision here, but if the code isn't in the header then the compiler _can't_ inline the code.

Comment: Oh okay. I didn’t know that putting the code in a header allowed the compiler to inline them. I thought this was only the case when adding the **inline** keyword.

Comment: The `inline` keyword is a tad bit of a misnomer. What it means is "allow this function to violate the ODR". Because the standard specifically says that a compiler can inline any function (if it can) or not inline any function, regardless of whether a given signature is marked `inline` or not. So to get a function to inline the only thing you can do is _allow_ the compiler to inline it by showing it the code; then it may or may not get inlined. That's as close as you can get. If you don't show the code (hide it in an implementation file) you can be sure it won't inline outside that CU.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thank you :)

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Compilers can do link-time code generation for some time now, enabling inlining even without the definition visible in the translation unit.

Comment: @GMan really? I didn't know that. But, we're talking about a compiler job here, that of generating code. So, the linker ... generates code?

Comment: @GMan if a function can inline at link-time then inlining is pretty much an optimization detail that's completely up to the compiler/linker, and the programmer absolutely has no say here.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: Yup, the linker generates code. (In fact, MSVC calls this option "Link-time Code Generation".) And yup, on a modern compiler inlining is pretty much no longer the worry of the programmer in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you decide on making a template library for the *right reasons*. Making a *container* library a template is a good reason: all containers of the standard C++ library are done as templates. Simply avoiding the link step *alone* is not a good reason.